# How to Exclude an URL for Apache Mod_proxy?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

We have two Apache server as front-end and 4 tomcat server as back-end configured using mod_proxy module as load balancer. Now, we want to exclude an single tomcat url from the mod_proxy load balancer. Is there any way or rule to exclude?

Proxy Balancer Setting:

```
<Proxy balancer://backend-cluster1>
   BalancerMember http://10.0.0.1:8080 loadfactor=1 route=test1 retry=10
   BalancerMember http://10.0.0.2:8080 loadfactor=1 route=test2 retry=10
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 53):

You exclude paths from mod_proxy with an exclamation mark (!) before your full ProxyPass statement, which your sample is missing - It would look something like `ProxyPass /path balancer://backend-cluster1`. Therefore, to exclude a path, add:

```
ProxyPass /my/excluded/path !
```

before

```
ProxyPass /my balancer://backend-cluster1
```

Comment: But the url to have access behind the proxyBalancer

Comment: Thanks fuzzyfelt, I am asking how to exclude the url if we configured the proxy balancer. I have included the proxy configuration in the question

Comment: See updated answer. Add an exclusion before you define which path to proxypass.

Comment: Using this answer worked great for allowing LetsEncrypt into the default .well-known folder location for a virtualhost, when using ProxyPass to show a chat server there.  Add before the other directives:    ProxyPass /.well-known !

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Alastair McCormack answer: If you use `<Location>`, you need to put the exception below instead of before:

```
<Location /my/>
    ProxyPass balancer://backend-cluster1
</Location>

<Location /my/excluded/path/>
    ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

Comment: I've been stuck on this for over a year, this one clarification just clicked it! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You could put a rewrite above the proxy directives that will give users a 404 error when they try to access the url you want to exclude.  You will need to enable rewrite_module.

```
<Location ~ ^/urltoblock($|/)>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
</Location>
```

Comment: He didn't say anything about wanting a 404 error.